# Именованное свойсто массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Насколько мне известно, массив - это список значений доступ к которым осуществляется по числовому индексу. Недавно натолкнулся на такой код:

```js
var arr = [];
arr['test'] = 'string';
console.log(arr['test']);
```

Не могу понять что в этом случае происходит?

```js
var arr = [];
arr['test'] = 'string';
console.log(arr.test);
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arr.test));
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arr));
console.log(arr.length);
```

Если создается именованное свойство у массива, то почему тогда его длина равна 0.
Судя по тому что к свойству можно обращаться через точку arr теперь объект, но Object.prototype.toString.call говорит об обратном.
Или же это поведение характерно массивам так же как функциям (им можно создавать свойства ) из за дальнего родственника в прототипе - Object.

Comment: [Ассоциативные массивы](https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/javascript-associative-arrays)

Comment: массив это объект, в объекте допустимы строковые ключи. length - это свойство со значением большим чем максимальный числовой индекс.

Comment: @AGS17, в яваскрипте нет ассоциативных массивов

Comment: @Grundy да, я в курсе. В той статье так и написано.

Comment: @Grundy уже есть https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @andreymal, это не совсем то, это просто объект, у которого ключами могут быть другие объекты, а не строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массивы **являются** объектами, поэтому любому массиву можно добавить свойство с не числовым именем.

Поэтому запись:

```
var arr = [];
arr['test'] = 'string';
```

Вполне допустима.

Но так как массив - это *особенный* объект, его методы и свойства рассчитаны на работу только со свойствами с числовыми именами.

Например, [length](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length) - это свойство, значение которого должно быть больше *любого числового индекса*. Отсюда видно, что оно никак не связано с *количеством* элементов в массиве, не говоря уже про свойства с не числовыми именами.